# Remove colon from title

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to remove colon from title

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
    \newtcbtheorem[no counter]{free}% environment name
                  {}% Title text
      {enhanced, % tcolorbox styles
      attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2.5mm},
      colback=white, colframe=black, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
      boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white},
      fonttitle=\bfseries,
      sharp corners=all,
      breakable
      }%
      {freee}% label prefix
     \begin{document}
     \begin{free}{Stochastic calculus}{}
    Stochastic calculus is a branch of mathematics that operates on stochastic 
   processes. It allows a consistent theory of integration to be defined for 
   integrals of stochastic processes with respect to stochastic processes. It is 
  used to model systems that behave randomly.
    \end{free}
     \noindent\textbf{Solution \ref{ex:sets}.}
     \end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `separator sign none`. But please note that as you do not specify a title you have to apply a dirty manual hack (seemingly the use without title is not intended).

[image: tcb theorem]

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
    \newtcbtheorem[no counter]{free}% environment name
                  {\hskip-.3em}% Title text
      {enhanced, % tcolorbox styles
      attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2.5mm},
      colback=white, colframe=black, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
      boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white},
      fonttitle=\bfseries,
      sharp corners=all,
      breakable,
      separator sign none,
      }%
      {freee}% label prefix
     \begin{document}
     \begin{free}{Stochastic calculus}{}
    Stochastic calculus is a branch of mathematics that operates on stochastic 
   processes. It allows a consistent theory of integration to be defined for 
   integrals of stochastic processes with respect to stochastic processes. It is 
  used to model systems that behave randomly.
    \end{free}
     \noindent\textbf{Solution \ref{ex:sets}.}
     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do not just use `\newtcolorbox` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
\newtcolorbox{free}[1][0]
{enhanced, % tcolorbox styles
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2.5mm},
  colback=white, colframe=black, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  sharp corners=all,
  title={#1},
  breakable
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{free}[Stochastic calculus]
  Stochastic calculus is a branch of mathematics that operates on stochastic 
  processes. It allows a consistent theory of integration to be defined for 
  integrals of stochastic processes with respect to stochastic processes. It is 
  used to model systems that behave randomly.
\end{free}
\noindent\textbf{Solution \ref{ex:sets}.}
\end{document}
```

[image]